# Fastlane Unsupported directory name(s) for screenshots/metadata in ‘./metadata’: ar-SA

Tags: ios, ruby, fastlane

I am attempting to upload images to the App Store for my app using Fastlane. However, I am getting this error:

```
[!] Unsupported directory name(s) for screenshots/metadata in 

'./metadata': ar-SA
Valid directory names are: ["ca", "cs", "da", "de-DE", "el", "en-AU", "en-CA", "en-GB", "en-US", "es-ES", "es-MX", "fi", "fr-CA", "fr-FR", "he", "hi", "hr", "hu", "id", "it", "ja", "ko", "ms", "nl-NL", "no", "pl", "pt-BR", "pt-PT", "ro", "ru", "sk", "sv", "th", "tr", "uk", "vi", "zh-Hans", "zh-Hant", "appleTV", "iMessage", "default"]

Enable 'ignore_language_directory_validation' to prevent this validation from happening
```

I can't seem to figure out how I should run this `ignore_language_directory_validation` parameter. The Fastlane documentation provides no clear example of how to do this.

My question is: What is the command I need run to ignore language validation.

The command I am currently running :

```
fastlane run deliver APP_ID="com.myapp"; APP_VERSION="1.3.0"; bundle exec fastlane deliver upload_screenshots --app_identifier "$APP_ID" --app_version "$APP_VERSION" --screenshots_path ~/screenshots --skip_metadata
```

Comment: Please provide the command your are _currently_ running.

Comment: @janpio provided

Answer (score 1):

*Write te command like below, by adding the specific parameter* `ignore_language_directory_validation`

**Command:-**

```
bundle exec fastlane deliver upload_screenshots --ignore_language_directory_validation true --app_identifier "$APP_ID" --app_version "$APP_VERSION" --screenshots_path ~/screenshots --skip_metadata true
```

Comment: I still get the same error and ignore_language_directory_validation | false

Comment: Why you want the parameter ignore_language_directory_validation to false?

Comment: I am trying to push images to the appstore using fatlane and i get that error and to resolve the error a suugestion to ignore_language_directory_validation is given, hence im trying to see if that will solve the problem

Comment: Have you tried with this command adding ignore_language_directory_validation with true value??

Comment: thats what i am trying to set but i cant seem to get a command to set that value to true

Comment: I have already added the code in the answer, how to set it to true. Just copy it run in your terminal.

Comment: that code didnt work the property was still false after i ran it